# Names cut on the x axis of the boxplot

Tags: r

I'm trying to save a boxplot in .tiif format using the code below:

```
sample_01 <- c(6, 1, 6, 8, 9, 8, 7, 3, 4, 9)
sample_02 <- c(13, 17, 16, 22, 18, 14, 20, 20, 11, 19)
sample_03 <- c(25, 23, 26, 29, 29, 22, 30, 27, 26, 21)
sample_04 <- c(31, 37, 40, 36, 33, 34, 31, 32, 37, 35)
sample_05 <- c(41, 44, 43, 47, 45, 50, 41, 45, 43, 50)

tiff(file = "temp.tiff", width = 3200, height = 3200, units = "px", res = 300)
box <- boxplot(sample_01,sample_02,sample_03,sample_04,sample_05,
               names = c("sample_01","sample_02","sample_03","sample_04","sample_05"),
               ylab = 'Relative Abundance (%)',
               ylim = c(0,55),
               col = c('red','green','blue','orange','purple'),
               las=2,
               cex.axis = 1.5,
               cex.lab = 1.5
)
dev.off()
```

However, variable names are always cut on the graph's x-axis. I tried to use the parameter `par(mar = c ())` in several different ways but I was unable to solve the problem. I also changed the height and width values, but without success either. How can I proceed so that the names of the x-axis are saved whole.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the margin of your plot by using `par(mar = c(bottom,left,top,right))`.

As pointed it out by @AndersonNBarbosa, `par(mar(...)` need to be specified after `tiff(...)`:

```r
tiff(file = "temp.tiff", width = 3200, height = 3200, units = "px", res = 300)
par(mar = c(8,5,2,2))
box <- boxplot(sample_01,sample_02,sample_03,sample_04,sample_05,
               names = c("sample_01","sample_02","sample_03","sample_04","sample_05"),
               ylab = 'Relative Abundance (%)',
               ylim = c(0,55),
               col = c('red','green','blue','orange','purple'),
               las=2,
               cex.axis = 1.5,
               cex.lab = 1.5
)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

dc37, you noticed me a mistake you were making. In my script, I was using the command `par(mar=c()`) before `tiff()` and this was causing error in the graph with the example below:

```
par(mar = c(8,5,2,2))
tiff(...)
boxplot(...)
dev.off()
```

Therefore, when saving the image, the command `par(mar=c())` must come after `tiff()` to be all right. As I show below:

```
tiff(...)
par(mar = c(8,5,2,2))
boxplot(...)
dev.off()
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I forget to precise this detail. I edited my answer.